# Http failure response Spring Boot Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i  ran into the problem while making the crud application. i can add the records and view the records and delete the records while i update the records records not updated i got the problem on  ** Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED** ** 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

what i tried so i attached below.on the update part of the application

**CustomerController**

```
`@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200/")

@RequestMapping("api/v1/customer")
public class CustomerController
{
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;


@PostMapping(path = "/update")
public String updateCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerUpdateDTO customerUpdateDTO)
{
    String id = customerService.updateCustomers(customerUpdateDTO);
    return id;
}

}}`
```

**CustomerService**

`String updateCustomers(CustomerUpdateDTO customerUpdateDTO);`
`

**CustomerServiceIMPL**

```
`@Override
public String updateCustomers(CustomerUpdateDTO customerUpdateDTO)
{
    if (customerRepo.existsById(customerUpdateDTO.getCustomerid())) {
        Customer customer = customerRepo.getById(customerUpdateDTO.getCustomerid());


        customer.setCustomername(customerUpdateDTO.getCustomername());
        customer.setCustomeraddress(customerUpdateDTO.getCustomeraddress());
        customer.setMobile(customerUpdateDTO.getMobile());
        customerRepo.save(customer);
    }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Customer ID do not Exist");
        }

            return null;
    }
```

**CustomerRepo**

```
`@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<Customer,Integer> {
}
```

**Customer**

```
``@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id", length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int customerid;

    @Column(name = "customer_name", length = 50)
    private String customername;

    @Column(name = "customer_address", length = 60)
    private String customeraddress;

    @Column(name = "mobile", length = 12)
    private int mobile;

    public Customer(int customerid, String customername, String customeraddress, int mobile) {
        this.customerid = customerid;
        this.customername = customername;
        this.customeraddress = customeraddress;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String customername, String customeraddress, int mobile) {
        this.customername = customername;
        this.customeraddress = customeraddress;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public int getCustomerid() {
        return customerid;
    }

    public void setCustomerid(int customerid) {
        this.customerid = customerid;
    }

    public String getCustomername() {
        return customername;
    }

    public void setCustomername(String customername) {
        this.customername = customername;
    }

    public String getCustomeraddress() {
        return customeraddress;
    }

    public void setCustomeraddress(String customeraddress) {
        this.customeraddress = customeraddress;
    }

    public int getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(int mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "customerid=" + customerid +
                ", customername='" + customername + '\'' +
                ", customeraddress='" + customeraddress + '\'' +
                ", mobile=" + mobile +
                '}';
    }
```

**CustomerUpdateDTO**

```
``package com.Project.SpringAngular.DTO;

public class CustomerUpdateDTO {
    private int customerid;
    private String customername;
    private String customeraddress;
    private int mobile;

    public CustomerUpdateDTO(int customerid, String customername, String customeraddress, int mobile) {
        this.customerid = customerid;
        this.customername = customername;
        this.customeraddress = customeraddress;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public CustomerUpdateDTO() {
    }

    public int getCustomerid() {
        return customerid;
    }

    public void setCustomerid(int customerid) {
        this.customerid = customerid;
    }

    public String getCustomername() {
        return customername;
    }

    public void setCustomername(String customername) {
        this.customername = customername;
    }

    public String getCustomeraddress() {
        return customeraddress;
    }

    public void setCustomeraddress(String customeraddress) {
        this.customeraddress = customeraddress;
    }

    public int getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(int mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomerDTO{" +
                "customerid=" + customerid +
                ", customername='" + customername + '\'' +
                ", customeraddress='" + customeraddress + '\'' +
                ", mobile=" + mobile +
                '}';
    }
}`
`
```

**Angular**

```
setUpdate(data: any)
  {
   this.customername = data.customername;
   this.customeraddress = data.customeraddress;
   this.mobile = data.mobile;
   this.currentCustomerID = data.customerid;
  }
 
  UpdateRecords()
  {
    let bodyData = {
      "customername" : this.customername,
      "customeraddress" : this.customeraddress,
      "mobile" : this.mobile
    };
    
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8084/api/v1/customer/update"+ "/"+ this.currentCustomerID,bodyData,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((resultData: any)=>
    {
        console.log(resultData);
        alert("Employee Registered Updateddd")
        this.getAllCustomer();
        this.customername = '';
        this.customeraddress = '';
        this.mobile  = 0;

    });
  }
```